# How to access a specific structure in array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I have this:

```
typedef struct{
    field_1;
    field 2;
    .....
}student;

typedef struct{
    student record[100];
    int counter;
}List;
```

Then I want to add the information for each 'student', for example:

```
List *p;
gets(p->list[index]->field_1);
```

but when I compiled the code it threw this:

```
[Error] base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'student'
```

So why can't I point to 'list' and way to access a specific 'record' in 'list'?

Comment: Use the `.` operator instead of `->` (the second one)..

Comment: Or complentarty create an array of pointers to student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adding code snippet that may help you to read/write the values to the records.
>   Free the pointer to a struct when you're done.

```
typedef struct{
int age;
int marks;
}student;

typedef struct{
student record[100];
int counter;
}List;

int main()
{ 
    List *p = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));

    p->record[0].age = 15;
    p->record[0].marks = 50;
    p->counter = 1;
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice. I was asking about using the `malloc()` function. But will calling `sizeof(List)` create unused `counter` variables?

Comment: No it will not. It will allocate memory of 4 bytes for counter variable only.

Answer (score 1):

The list itself, `p`, is a pointer, but the value `record[100]` is not. You would use the `->` operator to access values from `p` then the `.` operator to access values from the member `records`.

Comment: Then can I use malloc() function instead of giving a fixed number of records? Will there be any problems?

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
  `p->record[index]->field_1`
```

it is expanded as

  `(*p).(*record[index]).field_1`

```
  record[index]`
```

itself returns a value so there is no sense in adding * operator before that. But you can use

`p->(record+index)->field_1`